# Get top level domain name from url (without subdomain) in asp.net / c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url, uri

I am trying to get root domain name from a URL and so far I am using `Request.Url.Authority` or `Request.Url.Host` and both are working fine for the URLs without subdomains. e.g.

URL: `http://www.example.com` both above methods return `www.example.com`

but from URL with sudomains in it they return subdomain as well.
e.g. `http://sub.example.com` they return `sub.example.com` and from `http://sub.sub.example.com` they return `sub.sub.example.com` and so on.

I want to get just `example.com` or `www.example.com` even from subdomain URL. Is there any way to get this without parsing? or not please suggest me something.

Please help me! Thanks

Comment: AFAIK .NET has no native way to do this. You've gone as far as .NET goes which is to automatically get the host including protocol and subdomains, you'll need to parse the rest yourself. I'm afraid I don't know of any libraries to do this for you.

Comment: @Equalsk: Thanks for the information, I can do the parsing but I was looking for a better solution may be without parsing. But seems like I have to use parsing after all.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to do this that will cover most cases, though probably not all edge cases:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static public string GetHostnameWithoutSubdomain(string url)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        if (uri.ToString().Contains("localhost"))
        {
            return uri.Authority;
        }
        string[] uriParts = uri.Host.Split('.');
        int lastIndex = uriParts.Length - 1;
        // Ensure that the URI isn't an IP address by checking whether the last part is a number or (as it should be) a top-level domain:
        if (uriParts[uriParts.Length - 1].All(char.IsDigit))
        {
            return uri.Host;
        }
        // If the URI has more than 3 parts and the last part has just two characters, e.g. "uk" in example.co.uk or "cn" in moh.gov.cn, it's probably a top-level domain:
        if (uriParts.Length > 3 && uriParts[lastIndex].Length <= 2)
        {
            return uriParts[lastIndex - 2] + "." + uriParts[lastIndex - 1] + "." + uriParts[lastIndex];
        }
        if (uriParts.Length > 2)
        {
            return uriParts[lastIndex - 1] + "." + uriParts[lastIndex];
        }
        return uri.Host;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetHostnameWithoutSubdomain("https://localhost:123/some/page"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetHostnameWithoutSubdomain("https://example.com/some/page"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetHostnameWithoutSubdomain("https://www.example.com/some/page"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetHostnameWithoutSubdomain("https://test.www.example.com/some/page"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetHostnameWithoutSubdomain("https://255.255.255.255/some/page"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetHostnameWithoutSubdomain("https://test.www.example.co.uk/some/page"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetHostnameWithoutSubdomain("https://www.moh.gov.cn/some/page"));
    }
}
```

This also works in a development setup with test environment different that the production domain, hence handling of the `localhost` edge case.

Output:

```
localhost:123
example.com
example.com
example.com
255.255.255.255
example.co.uk
moh.gov.cn
```